# Question about Chapman's *An involution on derangements*

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The (one-page-long) paper is available here:

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X00003101

To recap:

- For a permutation $\sigma$, we write $a_\sigma := \min \{ a \; | \; \sigma(a) < a \}$.
- For a permutation $\sigma$, we write $f(\sigma) := \begin{pmatrix} a_\sigma & n \end{pmatrix} \circ \sigma$.
- We fix a permutation $\sigma$ taking $n$ to $n-1$.
- $f(\sigma)$ is shown to be a derangement taking $n$ to $n-1$ with $\operatorname{sign} f(\sigma) = - \operatorname{sign} \sigma$.
- If $\tau = f(\sigma)$, it is shown that $a_\sigma = a_{f(\tau)}$.

I'm fine with all this.  It's the next step that bothers me:

- We then conclude that $f(\tau) = \sigma$.

I'm sure I'm just being dense, but I don't see why this follows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $a_\tau=a_\sigma$,

$$f(\tau)=(a_\tau\;n)\circ\tau=(a_\sigma\;n)\circ\tau=(a_\sigma\;n)\circ(a_\sigma\;n)\circ\sigma=\sigma\;.$$

(And of course $f(\tau)$ is defined in the first place because he’s also shown that $\tau\in D_{n,n-1}$.)